# Can you have different localleaders for different Vim plugins?

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I started using a plugin that conflicts with my existing maps, but instead of remapping all of it's maps, I just want to add a prefix. I thought I'd be able to do this with LocalLeader.

Vimdoc says:

> `<LocalLeader>` is just like `<Leader>`, except that it uses
>   "maplocalleader" instead of "mapleader".  `<LocalLeader>` is to be used
>   for mappings which are local to a buffer.

It seems that the only way to set localleader is to set a global variable (the docs don't mention this, but `b:maplocalleader` didn't work):

```
let maplocalleader = '\\'
```

And I don't see how I'd cleanly unset that variable (an autocmd that clears it after plugins are setup!?)

Is there a way to do this? Or is LocalLeader only to give one global prefix and one filetype-specific prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last hunch is correct. If the plugin uses `<Leader>` (and it should unless it's a filetype plugin), there's no use in messing with `maplocalleader`.

Remapping is canonically done via `<Plug>` mappings, which the plugin hopefully offers. Some plugins do define a lot of similar mappings, some of those define a `g:pluginname_mappingprefix` (or so) variable to save you from having to remap all mappings individually. If your plugin doesn't, maybe write a suggestion / patch to the plugin author.

Comment: So in my case, I'd have to ask the plugin author to add the ability to specify a custom prefix? (I guess they could use LocalLeader to do this if they save the current value, set the configured value, and restore the saved value when they're done.)

Comment: If there are `<Plug>` mappings, the plugin (whose name you didn't tell us) doesn't need to be changed, it's just tedious for many mappings. A custom prefix would rather be something like `<Leader>c` or `,c`; as I said, LocalLeader is meant for buffer-local mappings.

Answer (score 2):

While @IngoKarkat solution is a prefered one, there is a hack which lets you do what you want: the `SourcePre` event:

```
autocmd SourcePre *               :let maplocalleader='\\'
autocmd SourcePre plugin-name.vim :let maplocalleader='_'
```

. This works for `<Leader>` as well. There are lots of cases when this won’t work though. You can as well use `SourceCmd` for this job, using something like

```
function s:Source(newmll)
    try
        let oldmll=g:maplocalleader
        let g:maplocalleader=a:newmll
        source <amatch>
    finally
        let g:maplocalleader=oldmll
    endtry
endfunction
let maplocalleader='\\'
autocmd SourceCmd plugin-name.vim :call s:Source('_')
```

in `SourceCmd` is the only way I see to restore `maplocalleader` after plugin was sourced, but `SourceCmd` event here won’t be launched for any file sourced inside `plugin-name.vim`. For some poorly written plugins (I mean, those that emit errors while sources) putting `:source` inside a `:try` block will break execution at the point where error occurs. Should not happen most of time though. You may also want to use `*/ftplugin/plugin-name.vim` as a pattern instead of `plugin-name.vim`.